# Facebook "og:img" not updating?

Tags: html, facebook

I've tried to update the image on my website which is: www.lux-boutique.co.uk and the image that is displayed when on facebook isn't updating to my new one.

Any ideas?

I have used the facebook debugger tool, it just comes up with my old one. It won't update to my new one. I've even deleted the old picture from cPanel yet it still comes up.

Link to the og:img is http://www.lux-boutique.co.uk/fblogo.png and the code in my header is

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.lux-boutique.co.uk/fblogo.png"/>
```

Comment: Link to the og:img is http://www.lux-boutique.co.uk/fblogo.png

Answer (score 1):

This is common, Facebook caches OG data, so you can actually check to see if it's working by using the debug tool

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

hope this helps!

EDIT

If that doesn't work, you can try this manual scrape with a smal jQuery ajax post with something like

```
$.post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com',
    {
        id: 'http://www.lux-boutique.co.uk/the/url/to/share',
        scrape: true
    },
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

If this doesn't help, could you share the link to to the OG image and how you're including it? Maybe that would help.

Comment: Where would I place that code? I'm unfamiliar with jQuery & Ajax. I've updated original post. @pj100

Comment: I just scraped it one more time and it seems to be working :) https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lux-boutique.co.uk%2F